# Which device capabilities restrict an app to iPhone 5S?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that requires very high performance and it is made for iPhone 5S only. It is not 64 bit yet. Which "required device capabilities" would restrict it to iPhone 5S?

Comment: The fingerprint sensor, to name one.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring a device capability without using will likely cause your app to be **rejected**.

#### EDIT

I found an [updated list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) and it looks like there's not key you can require in order to rule out the iPhone 5S.

In the list `armv6` and `armv7` are listed but `armv7s` is not, so it looks like you cannot require it.